# Pygame pop() class crashing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

In my game I am trying to make with pygame i have my player able to shoot "bullets" created from instances of a class in an array (named "shots"), but when i try to delete them, the program crashes. Below is my code, what am I doing wrong that makes it crash?

```
for i in range(len(shots)):
    shots[i].shoot()
    shots[i].drawBullet()

    if shots[i].x > swidth or shots[i].x < 0:
        shots.pop(i)
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that you traverse the list while you remove (`pop`) items. When you remove the last item of the list, then index of the item is still contained in the range `range(len(shots))`, but the access to `shots[i]` will fail.
A simple fix would be to traverse the list in reverse order. Reverse the range by [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```py
for i in reversed(range(len(shots))):
    shots[i].shoot()
    shots[i].drawBullet()

    if shots[i].x > swidth or shots[i].x < 0:
        shots.pop(i)
```

---

Another option would be to iterate a shallow copy of the list ([:]) and to remove elements from the original list. See [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```py
for shot in shots[:]:
    shot.shoot()
    shot.drawBullet()

    if shot.x > swidth or shot.x < 0:
        shots.remove(shot)
```

Comment: THANKS!!! I love it when the solution is to literally add one word.